# vim: how to set triggers as those in option-window

Tags: vim

When you type ':option' in vim, the first lines say:

```
" Each "set" line shows the current value of an option (on the left).
" Hit <CR> on a "set" line to execute it.
"            A boolean option will be toggled.
"            For other options you can edit the value before hitting <CR>.
" Hit <CR> on a help line to open a help window on this option.
" Hit <CR> on an index line to jump there.
" Hit <Space> on a "set" line to refresh it.
```

What are these and how can I set these four functions to my custom files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done with key mappings that invoke functions. The script that does it all is located at `$VIMRUNTIME/optwin.vim`. Have a look to see details.